# Установка MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

1. Я взял распаковал архив в домашнюю папку. Назвал распакованную папку mongodb
2. Создал папку data в mongodb
3. В home/name/mongodb/bin создал файл и прописал в нем dbpath=/home/name/mongodb/data

Что дальше? Как запустить файл из консоли на Линуксе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А документация для чего дана?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

УСТАНОВКА
(Лучше всего по документации, указанной Barmaley'ем постом выше.)
Но можно и так:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Чтобы предотвратить автоматические обновления:

```
echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Запуск/Остановка/Перезапуск/Статус MongoDB:

```
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod stop
sudo service mongod restart
sudo service mongod status (или sudo systemctl status mongodb)
```

УДАЛЕНИЕ

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```